# Not reading .val() of some inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="inLabel go-bottom hvz-street-smaller">
        <div class="inLabelDiv">
            <input type="text" name="locStreetAddress" id="locStreetAddress" placeholder="Straße" class="hvz-form-control triggerAddress">
            <label for="locStreetAddress">Straße</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inLabel go-bottom hvz-number-smaller">
        <div class="inLabelDiv">
            <input type="text" name="locNumber" id="locNumber" placeholder="HNr." class="hvz-form-control triggerAddress">
            <label for="locNumber">HNr.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="inLabel go-bottom hvz-zip-smaller">
        <div class="inLabelDiv">
            <input type="text" name="locZip" id="locZip" placeholder="Postleitzahl" class="hvz-form-control triggerPrice triggerAddress" value="">
            <label for="locZip">Postleitzahl</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inLabel go-bottom hvz-city-smaller">
        <div class="inLabelDiv">
            <input type="text" name="locCity" id="locCity" placeholder="Stadt" class="hvz-form-control triggerAddress" value="">
            <label for="locCity">Stadt</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inLabel go-bottom hvz-country-smaller">
        <div class="inLabelDiv">
            <input type="text" name="locCountry" id="locCountry" placeholder="Land" class="hvz-form-control triggerAddress" value="Deutschland">
            <label for="locCountry">Land</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For each `.triggerAddress`input I do this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.triggerAddress', function (event) {
    var street = $('#locStreetAddress').val();
    var number = $('#locNumber').val();
    var zip = $('#locZip').val();
    var city = $('#locCity').val();
    var country= $('#locCountry').val();
    var address = street + ' ' + number + ', ' + zip + ' ' + city + ', ' + country;
    if(street !== '' && number !== '' && zip !== '' && city !== '' && country !== ''){
        //..DO STUFF
    }else{
        console.log(address);
    }
});
```

Unfortunatley, `var street` and `var number` never get any value? Doing `console.log(street)` or `console.log($('#locStreetAddress').val())` returns a blank line for street and number.
All the other fields work as intended.

What am I missing?

//EDIT
Final Edit / Cleanup
It is an issue with featherlight.js I am using: https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/issues/122
For future reference: To update/read inputs properly, make `persist: true` and everything is working as intended.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5kppvrj8/. Check your console for errors, and make sure you haven't got multiple elements with the same `id` attribute

Comment: Checked it, none are duplicates. Even renaming does not help. I'll check again.

Comment: Please refer to https://gist.github.com/brandonaaskov/1596867

Comment: @Bsienn Please stop telling people to add JSfiddles. That isn't how this site works. Your question cannot depend on JSFiddle for meaning. If you have a JavaScript/HTML/CSS problem, use the built-in code editor.

Answer (score 0):

`change`  to `input type="text"` acts more like `blur`

You can use `input,keypress,keyup,paste`

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yeux2r74/)

**EDIT**

Check this line

```
if(street !== '' && number !== '' && zip !== '' && city !== '' && country !== '')
```

You are using `&&` so if loop will execute when none of them are empty, otherwise else loop

Check this second [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yeux2r74/3/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yeux2r74/2/ please see this. When you 'change' the street, the alert is triggered with the correct values. This does not explain my problem, but `change` does apply to input?!